# Duplicate contact when i log with this one

Tags: duplicate-contacts

Apparently when i'm trying to log with a contact, this one is duplicate :-/
Someone said that it could be because the wp email is different of civi email but in my case both are the same. If someone knows how to resolve it :)

Have a nice day

Comment: Sorry but could you clarify your problem. How to you come to this conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

You can dedupe contacts in two ways in CiviCRM.

The first one to do a search and find both contacts and then check the checkbox in front of both contacts and select the Merge Contacts from the action list (screenshot is in Dutch).

[image: Merge from search]

The other way is from the dedupe functionality under the Contacts --> Dedupe menu.

You have to select a rule and it will try to find matching contacts which you could then merge.